# Broken WF4 workflow rehydration

Tags: wcf, persistence, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

Consider a WF4 project running in IIS, with a single workflow definition (xamlx) and a SqlInstanceStore for persistence.
Instead of hosting the xamlx directly, we host a WorkflowServiceHostFactory which spins up a dedicated WorkflowServiceHost on a seperate endpoint for every customer.

This has been running fine for a while, until we required a new version of the workflow definition, so now on top of Flow.xamlx I have Flow1.xamlx. 
Since all interactions with the workflow service are wrapped with business logic which is smart enough to identify the required version, this homebrew versioning works fine for newly started workflows (both on Flow.xamlx and Flow1.xamlx).

However, workflows started before this change fail to be reactivated (on a post the servicehost throws an UnknownMessageReceived exception).
Since WF isn't overly verbose in telling you WHY it can't reactivate the workflow (wrong version, instance not found, lock, etc), we attached a SQL profiler to the database.

It turns out the 'WorkflowServiceType' the WorkflowServiceHost uses in its queries is different from the stored instances' WorkflowServiceType. Likely this is why it fails to detect the persisted instance.

Since I'm pretty sure I instance the same xamlx, I can't understand where this value is coming from. What parameters go into the calculation of this Guid, does the environment matter (sitename), and what can I do to reactivate the workflow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I decompiled System.Activities.DurableInstancing. The only setter for WorkflowHostType on SqlWorkflowInstanceStore was in ExtractWorkflowHostType:

```
private void ExtractWorkflowHostType(IDictionary<XName, InstanceValue> commandMetadata)
{
    InstanceValue instanceValue;
    if (commandMetadata.TryGetValue(WorkflowNamespace.WorkflowHostType, out instanceValue))
    {
        XName xName = instanceValue.Value as XName;
        if (xName == null)
        {
            throw FxTrace.Exception.AsError(new InstancePersistenceCommandException(SR.InvalidMetadataValue(WorkflowNamespace.WorkflowHostType, typeof(XName).Name)));
        }
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xName.ToString());
        base.Store.WorkflowHostType = new Guid(HashHelper.ComputeHash(bytes));
        this.fireRunnableInstancesEvent = true;
    }
}
```

I couldn't clearly disentangle the calling code path, so I had to find out at runtime by attaching WinDbg/SOS to IIS and breaking on HashHelper.ComputeHash.

I was able to retreive the XName that goes into the hash calculation, which has a localname equal to the servicefile, and a namespace equal to the [sitename]/[path]/.

In the end the WorkflowHostType calculation comes down to:

```
var xName = XName.Get("Flow.xamlx.svc", "/examplesite/WorkflowService/1/");
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xName.ToString());
var WorkflowHostType = new Guid(HashHelper.ComputeHash(bytes));
```

Bottomline: apparently workflows can only be rehydrated when the service filename, sitename and path are all identical (case sensitive) as when they were started

Comment: I have found a couple of things that look promising:
If I have .xamlx hosted instance and move to a .svc, then change the path in the servicedeployments table, I can go into the AppFabric management console and attempt to suspend a workflow. I then get a very clear message that there is a mismatch in the host objects with the addresses of both hosts shown aswell.

The host string is most likely stored in one of the blobs in the instancestable. Perhaps you could change the stored data to make it appear as if it started on a .svc host.

Comment: Ruurd, I'm running into a similar issue. The WorkflowHostType guid in the InstancesTable is not the same as I'm generating in code. I need to see how is it computing WorkflowHostType. How did you get the source/debug symbols to step into the computeHash function?

Comment: I didn't step into the computeHash function. As I just wanted to know the input for the hash calculation - same in => same out - and arguments higher up in the stack, breaking on the function entry was enough. If you want to see the calculation check the reference source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Internals/System/Runtime/HashHelper.cs